# Using beaker sessions for checking if user is authenticated in Pyramid

Tags: python, session, authentication, pyramid

I'm creating a webapp using Pyramid with Beaker sessions.
I would like to store user id in `request.session['user_id']` and some other info after successful signing in and then use it for checking if user already signed in:

```
if 'user_id' in request.session:
    # user signed in
else:
    # user not signed in or session is expired
```

The question is: is it safe to rely on sessions or it will be better and/or safer to use Pyramid's `authenticated_userid()` with `remember()` and `forget()` from `pyramid.security`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use pyramid_beaker and the [SessionAuthenticationPolicy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html#pyramid.authentication.SessionAuthenticationPolicy), then use `pyramid.authentication.authenticated_userid()` to check if they're logged in or not. If it returns `None`, they're not.

Comment: What should I do to get actual user id with `authenticated_userid()`? Should I pass somewhere headers I get from `remember()`?

Comment: Do like the "login" view here: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.2/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html#adding-login-and-logout-views .. set the result of remember into response headers.

Comment: I'm just calling `remember()` and then all works exactly as needed. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer